# How can I return a single property from an object in a mongoDB query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query that looks like this:

```
listProjectQry = [
    {
      $match: {
        city: city
      }
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        rating: 1,
        title: 1,
        amenities: 1
      }
    }
  ]
```

This works fine but the amenities object actually maps to an array of amenity objects that themselves contain multiple fields. Right now I'm getting the entire array of amenities, but I'm wondering if I can make an array of just the IDs of the amenities and send that back down to the clients.

The intent is to make the query more performant and take less time. Maybe this optimization wouldn't help make it faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use the dot notation:

```
{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        rating: 1,
        title: 1,
        "amenities._id": 1
    }
}
```

which will return an array of objects with one property `_id` or use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to get an array of values

```
amenityIds: {
    $map: {
        input: "$amenities",
        in: "$$this._id"
    }
}
```

Comment: @micki This worked! Thank you. I just realized, however, that there is one more aspect I forgot to take into consideration. I basically need to return the amenity ID if a boolean value on the amenity is true. But if it isn't true, then it doesn't need to be returned. Is there a quick fix for that? I went with the dot notation approach.

Comment: @Westley you can try $map with $filter if you want to remove those documents or $map with $cond if you just want to hide them